# At what stage in a control's lifetime can it access inherited attached properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties, object-lifetime

I have a control that uses a certain inherited attached property, and I found that I can't access that property in the constructor, which is reasonable, since at that stage the control isn't a part of the visual tree and so it can't inherit any attached properties.

```
// Constructor
public MyClassName()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyValue value = DeclaringClass.GetMyAttachedProperty(depObj); // value == null
}
```

When I try to access the property during the `Loaded` event, I am able to retrieve the value:

```
// Constructor
public MyClassName()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= OnLoaded;

    MyValue value = DeclaringClass.GetMyAttachedProperty(depObj); // value != null

    // Do something with value
}
```

So this brings me to my question - what is the earliest stage in the control's lifetime where it can access inherited attached properties? Is there a better place to do so instead on the `Loaded` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest possible is indeed inside the `Loaded` event handler. Your only other choice is the constructor (or the morally equivalent `Initialized` event) but that's too soon for dependency properties to assume inherited values.

See also [common object lifetime events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx#common_events) at MSDN.